# SSRS 2008 - Display Multi Value Parameter selections on individual excel tabs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that has a page break between each instance of a group. The field that I am breaking on is also a multi valued parameter within my report. What I would like to do is export the report and have each tab named after the value that is selected for each page.

For example, if I have a multi value parameter that has the selections: Cat, Dog, Bird, Fish and I have my table set to break on the field AnimalNames, which is the same field that I use for my parameter and I select Dog and Bird and I want to see the data for Dog and Bird on two separate tabs, how do I get each tab named after my selections?

I've tried Parameter.AnimalName.Value but that just names each tab after my first selection within the parameter.

Please Help!!!

Comment: You should name the page after the **field**, not the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with one of my reports. Try setting the page name to:

```
=First(Fields!AnimalName.Value, "AnimalNameDataSet")
```